# ¿Guardar en base de datos múltiples peticiones de socket sin tumbar el servidor?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, socket, gps

Tengo un proyecto personal sobre `Gpstraking`. He hecho un socketServer UDP donde me llegarán los reportes de los `GPS`. Por el momento estoy usando `MySQL` para la base de datos y `Java` para el socket.

Imaginen que tengo más de 1000 `GPS` reportando al socket y más de 1 al mismo tiempo quiere guardar sus datos, pueden ser 100, 200 o muchos más queriendo guardar al mismo tiempo. He ahí mi miedo: que me tumbe el servicio de la base de datos.

Estaba pensando en guardar todo en un blog y cada tanto tiempo leer las peticiones entre una hora y otra y mandarlo con la librería `BeanUtils` de `java` a la base de datos de una forma más comprimida y no inserción por inserción y así no atacar `MySQL` tantas veces, pero los datos no estarían 100% en tiempo real, entonces, sigo viendo que debe llegar cada mensaje y guardarlo individualmente.

Comment: Hola Ruben, Bienvenido al sitio, seria bueno que expreses en código la solución que tienes en mente, así te podemos ayudar mejor. Cómo está redactada la pregunta, son muchas las dudas que surgen para pensar una solución a tu problema. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Podrias implementar un sistema de actores como akka

http://akka.io/

Los actores son unidades de programación que utilizan una cola de entrada de peticiones(inbox), por lo tanto si llegan muchas peticiones se van quedando en la cola esperando ser atendidas y el actor las atiende de una en una,  de esta manera tendrás un flujo controlado contra la base de datos. Si esto es muy lento puedes levantar tantos actores como quieras hasta llevar a su limite a la base pero de manera controlada.

Y si la base ya esta en su limite ya solo puedes ampliar el hardware o cambiar a una estructura de cluster para darle mas capacidad.

Comment: me gusta la idea, suena bien, pero luego de esto haré un sistema web para monitorear las unidades, esta pagina tendrá varios CRUD a la base de datos, la tabla Historial la tabla maestra donde ahi estarán los mensajes del gps(el problema antes mencionado), ¿no tendré problemas con eso?
Aun estoy pensando si hacerlo en Ruby on Rails, en Php con Laravel, ¿o que me recomendarias? e escuchado hablar de PrimeFaces para java, no tengo mucha experiencia y seria mi primer proyecto persona y de un nivel mas alto de lo ya hecho desde que egrese.

Comment: @RubénMiller PF es un framework de front-end hecho en Java, la implementación de tu proyecto va a depender de ¿con qué lenguaje te sientes más cómodo a la hora de programar?. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la informacion de PF

Comment: con akka puedes ordenar el backoffice de tu proyecto, debes enteder los beneficios de su filosofia antes de decidirte a implementarlo, puedes comenzar con esta explicacion https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/introduccion-a-akka-para-java-con-ejemplos/. por el lado de frontoffice, hay muchas alternativas, pero personalmente para cientos de usuarios no usuaria faces, ya que he visto que esta muy amarrado al server, osea que la capa visual le pega mucho al servidor y lo puede sobrecargar.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] más de 1 al mismo tiempo quiere guardar sus datos, pueden ser 100, 200 o muchos mas querer guardar al mismo tiempo [...]
>
> [...] Estaba pensando en guardar todo en un log, y cada tanto tiempo leer las peticiones entre una hora y otra [...]

#### Ejecución en *batch*

En JDBC es posible ejecutar múltiples sentencias como una sola unidad en una única llamada, algo también conocido como un ***batch***. Si agrupas las inserciones en *batches*, reduces el número de viajes hacía la base de datos  (segunda imagen<sup>1</sup>) y por lo tanto, el rendimiento mejora.

[image: Una única sentencia]

[image: Múltiples sentencias]

Por ejemplo, si deseas insertar todos los elementos de una lista como una sola unidad, entonces el código puede ser similar a:

```
void batchInsert(List<String> list) {
    try {
        String sql = "insert into mensaje (texto) values (?)";
        try (Connection connection = getConnection();
             PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            for (String mensaje : list) {
                ps.setString(1, mensaje);
                ps.addBatch();
            }
            ps.executeBatch();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // Hacer algo
    }
}
```

#### Usando una *cola*

Ahora, tú necesitas una forma de ir agrupando los reportes que recibes de los GPS's. Hay varias formas de hacerlo. Mi sugerencia es que utilices una ***cola***, donde el primer elemento en entrar, es también el primero en salir (FIFO). Más específicamente, una [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)<sup>2</sup>, la cual, adicionalmente, bloquea el hilo *consumidor* hasta que haya elementos que *consumir*.

```
BlockingDeque<String> queue = Queues.newLinkedBlockingDeque();
```

`BlockingQueue` tiene el método [`drainTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo-java.util.Collection-int-), que permite remover cierto número de elementos y pasarlos a una colección. No obstante, la librería [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), a través de la clase [`Queues`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Queues.html) permite hacer la remoción con un tiempo de espera máximo, [`drainUninterruptibly`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Queues.html#drainUninterruptibly(java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue, java.util.Collection, int, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).  Por ejemplo, si deseas pasar 50 elementos de la cola a una lista con un tiempo máximo de un segundo (o 1000 milisegundos), entonces:

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList();
Queues.drainUninterruptibly(queue, list, 50, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Si la cola tiene más de 50 elementos, entonces no hay tiempo de espera... pero si no alcanzan, entonces se esperan máximo 1000 milisegundos a que se completen... si no se completan, entonces los que estén. Si no hay ningún elemento, entonces la lista (`list`) será vacía. Esto debe hacerse en un hilo independiente.

#### Código de ejemplo

Es decir, complementando el código anterior:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlockingDeque<String> queue = Queues.newLinkedBlockingDeque();
    new Thread(new Consumidor(queue)).start();
    try {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(4445);
        while (true) {
            try {
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
                socket.receive(packet);
                String mensaje = new String(packet.getData());
                queue.add(mensaje);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Enviar al log
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // Enviar al log
    }
}
```

```
class Consumidor implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingDeque<String> queue;
    Consumidor(BlockingDeque<String> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList();
            Queues.drainUninterruptibly(queue, list, 50, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                batchInsert(list);
            }
        }
    }
    void batchInsert(List<String> list) {
        try {
            String sql = "insert into mensaje (texto) values (?)";
            try (Connection connection = getConnection();
                    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                for (String mensaje : list) {
                    ps.setString(1, mensaje);
                    ps.addBatch();
                }
                ps.executeBatch();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // Hacer algo
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes disminuir el tiempo, por ejemplo, a 100 milisegundos.  También puedes incrementar el número de elementos (para efectos prácticos, el número de sentencias), aunque éste estará limitado por [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet). Te recomiendo utilizar un *pool* de conexiones<sup>3</sup> para evitar el costo de conexión utilizando únicamente `DriverManager.getConnection`.

---

*Notas*

1. Imágenes tomadas de [*JDBC Batch y rendimiento - Arquitectura Java*](http://www.arquitecturajava.com/jdbc-batch-y-rendimiento/).
2. Veáse, por ejemplo, [*5 cosas que usted no sabía acerca de... java.util.concurrent*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ssa/java/library/j-5things4/).
3. Puede usarse para este propósito la clase `BasicDataSource`. Más en [*Pool de conexiones: BasicDataSource*](http://www.chuidiang.com/java/mysql/BasicDataSource-Pool-Conexiones.php).